# Sublists with vertically typeset titles

Tags: lists

[image: tblr]

I can typeset something like that using tables:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tblr}{Q[r, m]rl}
    & \textbf{Code} & \textbf{Explanation} \\
    \SetCell[r = 5]{r, m} \rotatebox[origin = c]{90}{\bfseries Group 1}
      & 01 & Code 01 \\
      & 02 & Code 02 \\
      & 03 & Code 03 \\
      & 04 & Code 04 \\
      & 05 & Code 05 \\
    \hline
    \SetCell[r = 5]{r, m} \rotatebox[origin = c]{90}{\bfseries Group 2}
      & 06 & Code 06 \\
      & 07 & Code 07 \\
      & 09 & Code 09 \\
      & 10 & Code 10 \\
      & 11 & Code 11 \\
      \hline
    \SetCell[r = 5]{r, m} \rotatebox[origin = c]{90}{\bfseries Group 3}
      & 12 & Code 12 \\
      & 13 & Code 13 \\
      & 14 & Code 14 \\
      & 15 & Code 15 \\
      & 16 & Code 16
  \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, some entries also need to have footnotes, and tables don't support footnotes. Is there a way to achieve a similar effect with lists? `description` with nested `itemize` doesn't look pretty:

```latex
\documentclass[paper = a6, fontsize = 9pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{description}
    \item[\protect{\rotatebox[origin = c]{90}{\bfseries Group 1}}] \begin{itemize}
      \item[01] Code 01\footnote{Ugly, but with footnotes}
      \item[02] Code 02
      \item[03] Code 03
      \item[04] Code 04
      \item[05] Code 05
    \end{itemize}
    \hrule
    \item[\protect{\rotatebox[origin = c]{90}{\bfseries Group 2}}] \begin{itemize}
      \item[06] Code 06
      \item[07] Code 07
      \item[09] Code 09
      \item[10] Code 10
      \item[11] Code 11
    \end{itemize}
    \hrule
    \item[\protect{\rotatebox[origin = c]{90}{\bfseries Group 3}}] \begin{itemize}
      \item[12] Code 12
      \item[13] Code 13
      \item[14] Code 14
      \item[15] Code 15
      \item[16] Code 16
    \end{itemize}
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: itemize]